# Prevent bootstrap-datepicker from showing future months

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datepicker

How can I restrict bootstrap-datepicker to show (not just disable) only certain months/years in future. Passing `endDate` only makes the date beyond the passed date disabled, but it still shows months well past the disabled date in the picker. I don't want to show any month/year in the datepicker beyond the date I pass.

EDIT: If it's possible to disable the next button (for navigating to the next year) if the next year is greater than a certain year I pass, then it will also work.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no built-in functionality to do what you are asking.

One way to hide disabled dates is adding a CSS rule targeting disabled elements. Each disabled element has the `disabled` class. Moreover:

- Each *element* has a class for its type (days have the `day` class, months have the `month` class, years have `year` class, decades have `decade` class and centuries have `century` class)
- All elements are under a `div` with `datepicker` and `datepicker-dropdown` classes

You can use something like:

```css
td.disabled.day,
td>span.month.disabled,
td>span.year.disabled,
td>span.decade.disabled,
td>span.century.disabled {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

Or

```css
div.datepicker.datepicker-dropdown .disabled {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

Here a full live example:

```js
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
  endDate: new Date()
})
```

```css
td.disabled.day,
td>span.month.disabled,
td>span.year.disabled,
td>span.decade.disabled,
td>span.century.disabled{
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="form-control" id="datepicker">
```

Comment: Thanks @VincenzoC for answering but this doesn't solve the issue completely, as I don't see any way of hiding the entire datepicker for years that have all months disabled. The year navigator at top is never disabled, so it cannot be targeted just with CSS.

Comment: @dk49 I'm sorry that this code doesn't solve the issue completely. Can you explain me better what do you want to hide/disable? What do you mean with _year navigator_? The part between `<<` and `>>`?

Comment: I have managed to hide the "<<" and ">>" with CSS. But I now want to disable the year navigator which appears in between these arrows. There is no option to do that in the bootstrap-datepicker plugin. I guess I will have to write custom jquery for it. Any ideas how to go about it?

Comment: The _"year navigator"_ is a `th` with the `datepicker-switch` class, when clicked it probably fires events listed [here](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/events.html). I didn't exactly get when you want to disable/hide this element, otherwise I'll try to update my answer.

Comment: I managed to hide the the "<<" and ">>" with CSS. The plugin adds 'disabled' class to the next button when the year is out of range. But this is buggy as it's adding disabled class to the year one year prior to "endDate" I pass. So now I will have to disable the year navigator (`datepicker-switch`). I went through the events but there is no option to do that in the bootstrap-datepicker plugin. I guess I will have to write custom jquery for it.